# Unable to get mizzao/meteor-autocomplete to work with collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am using *mizzao/meteor-autocomplete* and am having problems in trying to get it to work.

When viewing the page in my browser, I am getting no results at all when typing any text. I've created the appropriate collection:

```
Institutions = new Mongo.Collection("institutions");
```

and know that there is data in the actual db, however still no success.

I've included my files below.

*publications.js* (located in the server folder)

```
Meteor.publish('institutions', function(args) {
    return Institutions.find({}, args);
});
```

*registrationStart.js*

I've two helpers; one that actually powers the search and the other that should be returning the institutions. I have also tried this with the `token: '@'` argument with no success.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Template.registrationStart.helpers({
    settings: function() {
        return {
            position: "top",
            limit: 7,
            rules: [{
                collection: Institutions,
                field: "name",
                options: '',
                matchAll: true,
                template: Template.institutionSelectDisplay
            }]
        };
    },

    institutions: function() {
        return Instititions.find();
    }
    });

    Template.registrationStart.events({
    "autocompleteselect input": function(event, template, doc) {
        // Session.set(event.target.name, event.target.value);
        console.log("selected: ", doc);
        console.log("event.target.name: ", event.target.name);
        console.log("event.target.value: ", event.target.value);
    }
    });

}
```

*registrationStart.html* template

```
<template name="registrationStart">
    <div class="panel-body" id="loginForm">
    <h2 class="pageTitle">veClient Registration</h2>
    <form>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <fieldset>
            {{> inputAutocomplete settings=settings id="institution" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="type institution here"}}
        </fieldset>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Continue Registration</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

And the template to be rendered

```
<template name="institutionSelectDisplay">
    <p class="inst-state">{{city}}, {{state}}</p>
    <p class="inst-name">{{name}}</p>
    <p class="inst-description">{{email}}</p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resulted because there was no subscription to the "institutions" publication. So need to add a subscribe statement to the registrationStart.js file:

```
Meteor.subscribe('institutions');
```